# Python delete only "new" attribute from a class?

Tags: python

I was going through the Python tutorial and encountered the following code:

```
x.counter = 1
while x.counter < 10:
    x.counter = x.counter * 2
print x.counter
del x.counter
```

Apparently `del` could delete an attribute from a class instance. I did some experiments and found out that only newly added attributes not inside class definition could be deleted.

```
class obj:
    a = 1
x = obj()
print x.a #this outputs 1
del x.a
```

and the following exception is raised.

```
AttributeError: obj instance has no attribute 'a'
```

Anyone could explain to me why?

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating an *instance* variable. So `a` doesn't belong to the namespace of `x` but the one of `obj`. You can delete it but you have to reference the namespace of `obj`:

```
del obj.a
```

To create *instance* variables instead you have to define a constructor:

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
x = obj()
del x.a
```

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.  It's the correct answer, with an explanation...

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it true that when we use x.a the interpreter will first look for a in x's namespace and then in x's class's namespace (obj)?